# Parse.com saveInBackground doesn't have progressCallback?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-progressbar

If I use this code:

```
object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e){
        ...
    }, new ProgressCallback(){
        @Override0
        public void done(Integer percentDone){
        ...
    }
}
```

I get a `cannot resolve method` for ProgressCallback, by, which I understood, means that SaveCallback doesn't have a ProgressCallback. So, is there a way I could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SaveInBackground() does **not** have a ProgressCallback. There is no way you can implement it other than creating your own ProgressBar and creating your own loading logic, which is pretty hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`ParseFile.saveInBackground()` has `ProgressCallback()`

But you are trying to use `ProgressCallback()` for `ParseObject.saveInBackground()` which does not exist. You can use `ProgressCallback()` for only with `ParseFile`.

Check out official documentation: [Android Developers Guide ProgressCallBack](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#progress)

Also check out API Referance: [Parse SDK Android API](http://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-Android/api/)